# Why Does This Chainlink Example Code Revert?

Tags: solidity, chainlink, polygon, chainlink-vrf, revert

I seem to be doing everything exactly as stated in the docs and example code I am following.

When I deploy this to polygon mumbai though and call "generateRandomNumber" it just reverts with no error message whatsoever...

Note: calling it on polygon mumbai network, and I have already sent some link token to the smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/v1.11.0/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract RandomNumberGenerator is VRFConsumerBase {

    uint256 public randomNumber;

    bytes32 public requestId;
    bytes32 public fullfilledId;

    address vrfCoordinator = 0x7a1BaC17Ccc5b313516C5E16fb24f7659aA5ebed;
    address linkAddress = 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB;

    constructor() VRFConsumerBase(vrfCoordinator, linkAddress) { }

    function generateRandomNumber() public {
    
        bytes32 _keyHash = 0x4b09e658ed251bcafeebbc69400383d49f344ace09b9576fe248bb02c003fe9f;
        uint256 _fee = 0.0005 * 10e18;

        requestId = requestRandomness(_keyHash, _fee);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        // require(requestId == _requestId, "Request Ids don't match!");

        fullfilledId = _requestId;

        randomNumber = randomness;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you used the legacy version of the VRF Consumer smart contract, which is **deprecated**. You should migrate to VRFv2, you can grab the [example consumer contract from the Chainlink official docs](https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2/subscription/examples/get-a-random-number).

Fyi, the calculation with `0.0005` is not a problem. The following contract works as expected:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
    function getFee() public pure returns(uint256) {
        uint256 _fee = 0.0005 * 10e18;
        return _fee;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solidity doesn't accept floar numbers like `0.0005` you clould change it for somethic like:

```
  uint256 _fee = 10e18 * 5 / 10e4;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you use the correct address for VRF
try this:
https://blog.chain.link/how-to-get-a-random-number-on-polygon/